# Getting jQuery and Ajax to Update a Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have encountered another jQuery problem with my page to display a table of dates and prices. The relevant part of the page is

```
<table align="center" width="100%" style="margin-top:6px">
<tr>
<td width="178">
<form name="StartDateCal" id="StartDateCal">
<input type="hidden" name="hid" id="hid" value="<?php echo $hid ?>">
From &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="pricePicker" size="15" value="<?php echo date("D, j M Y",strtotime($startdate)) ?>"> 
<input type="hidden" name="StartDate" id="StartDate">
<input type="hidden" name="defaultdate" id="defaultdate" value="<?php echo $startdate ?>">
<input type="text" name="currency" id="currency">
/*Change to "hidden" after debugging*/
</form>
</td>
<td class="prev">
<a href="#" id="previous"><< Previous</a>
</td>
<td style="padding:0 0 5px 0"></td>
<td class="prev" style="text-align:right">
<a href="#" id="next">Next >></a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div id="pricePickerResult"><br><img src="../images/ajax_loader_blue_64.gif" width="64" height="64" alt="Loading ..."><br><br></div>
<div style="float:right; line-height:18px">Change currency: <a href="#" id="euro"><img src="/images/price.png"></a> <a href="#" id="pound"><img src="/images/price_gbp.png"></a> <a href="#" id="dollar"><img src="/images/price_usd.png"></a></div>
```

At the end of the body is this javascript (along with links to some other external javascripts).

```
// Determines the currency according to language and timezone of browser.
var langCode = navigator.language || navigator.systemLanguage;
var lang = langCode.toLowerCase();
lang = lang.substr(0,2);

var dateObject = new Date();
var timeOffset = - dateObject.getTimezoneOffset() / 60; 

if (lang == 'en') {
    if (timeOffset == 0) {
        curr = "GBP";
    }else if ((timeOffset < -4)&&(timeOffset > -10)) {
        curr = "USD";
    }else{
        curr = "EUR";
    }
}else{
    curr = "EUR";
}
document.getElementById("currency").value = curr;
```

So for users in the UK the default currency will be GBP. For users in the USA and Canada it will be USD and foreveryone else it will be EUR.

The jQuery to get the data for the table is in a separate external javascript. That's working well, no problem. The same table also contains some code to change the default currency using the three images price.png, price_gbp.png and price_usd.png as links. The code I have to do that is

```
// Change currency to Euros, load ajax
$('a#euro').click(function () {
    var data = $('#StartDateCal').serializeArray();
    data.push({name: 'currency', value: 'EUR'});
        $.ajax ({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/includes/calendar_price.php',
        data: data,
        success: function(result) {
            $("#pricePickerResult").html(result);
        }
    });
$("#currency").value = 'EUR';
    return false;
});
```

This changes the content of the table (calendar_price.php) OK, but I need to feed back the new value of the variable "curr" to the parent page. By my reckoning,

```
$("#currency").value = 'EUR';
```

is supposed to do that, but it doesn't. The aim is to change the default currency so that the user can change currency, then change dates without jumping back to the original currency each time.

I have tried using the variable "curr" in place of the hard value "EUR' and I've tried $("input#currency") instead of $("#currency") but none of these things help.  It's driving me to distraction, yet I suspect that it's really something very simple. If you've managed to read through this long question, I would really appreciate your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `$("#currency").val('EUR');`? Here's the documentation page: http://api.jquery.com/val/. `$("#currency")` returns a jQuery object, unlike a native DOM element you can't set the value by changing the `value `property.

Comment: `.value` does not work for jQuery objects. Since `$("#currency")` is an set of elements, you could extract the HTML element like this: `$("#currency")[0].value = 'EUR';` But better to use *@Joe's* suggestion.

Comment: Isn't it so easy when you know? Joe's answer worked. And it all took less time than it took me to even ask the question! Thanks to you both. Unfortunately as you answered via a comment rather than an answer, I can't give it a big green tick.